# application not installed in some devices only

Tags: android, android-studio

my application install and run perfectly in my emulator , redmi note 5 , poco and some more devices but in some devices like android 11 its not install

please solve my promblem

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

}

android {
compileSdk 31

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cryptomasterquiz"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 2
    versionName "2.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
viewBinding{
    enabled = true
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

//implementation 'com.github.denzcoskun:ImageSlideshow:0.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.8.0.0'

implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.6.3'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.23'
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete, please mention when you are not able to install the app. while using ADB/sideloading the APK file?

If you are unable to sideload the apk then make sure that you are ticking both v1 and v2 options while generating the apk to support a wide range of devices.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you installed debug build in your mobile.. then you need to uninstall it and install signed build.

If it still not installed then your Application related data might be still there in your memory.. ex) if you created any DB from your Application then you need to delete that from memory and try to install your signed build again.

If it still not installed and if you are using lollipop devices.. your Application might be installed in other users account too.. you to switch to other users and go to Settings->Apps->your_application and uninstall it. even check Guest user. your application might be hiding in that too..

I had this issue.. just follow these steps.. then your application can be installed.. :)